# Is there a practical way to display limited records in a page and display the next set of records in next page during pagination in the dbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc web application with a webgrid and i need to load all records to webgrid. I'm using entity framework and while loading the bulk records, the paging getting long time to load .

Is there a practical way to display limited records in a page and display the next set of records in next page during pagination in the dbContext.

Answer (score 1):

The entire idea of pagination is so that you won't have to load all your records at one time on the page. Can you do it? Yes. Should you do it? Probably not because you have no idea how many records you are going to end up with overtime as your database grows.

Have you perhaps looked into caching the results from the database and then reading from cache? You can then just apply a pager and the performance will most likely be better.

One of the better pagers I have used as long as you don't want to roll your own is [MvcPager](http://en.webdiyer.com/mvcpager)

It uses a PagedList type that works really well and you can get it working fairly quickly with the MVC Web Grid if needed. Web Grid has it's own pager as well if you want to take a look at it a good sample can be found at [Web Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx)

Comment: @Tommy - data has a tendency to grow. Overtime. Not thinking about it ahead of time is a nice way to shoot yourself in the foot. That is all.

Comment: So...are you saying one should or should not use pagination.  I took your response to mean "should not".  Please let me know if I interpreted you incorrectly.

Comment: I say use pagination, minus the pull every record down to your browser. Sorry if it is not clear in my response.

Comment: Gotcha - the "should you do it, probably not" part is what made me think you meant to not use pagination.  Also, can you provide an example of pagination that the user could use (jqGrid, Mvc.Grid, etc)?

Comment: @Tommy I understand, I will update my response and post the link to a pager.